# eventlet.monkey_patch() is ignoring child processes

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, flask, socket.io, eventlet

I'm using flask-socketio library in my flask project and eventlet library is necessary to let the emit from child processes through monkey patching, but the problem is when doing `eventlet.monkey_patch()` the grand-child processes are being ignored. Anyone can help in clearing things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced all the `processes` with `threads`
Even the multi-processing i replaced it with thread pools
To make sure they have the same memory in the Ram
And avoid the collision with eventlet with multi-processing